# Can I get the HWND of an embedded Flash ActiveX control from browser control in my application?

Tags: c++, flash, com, activex, ole

It seems that in browsers, the Flash Control uses an optimized way of drawing. I could not achieve this while embedding the control directly (fast animations are choppy in the control I directly embed, not in a browser). I have found an open source project that [implements an optimized drawing](http://lists.helixcommunity.org/pipermail/datatype-dev/2007-April/005497.html), however it is pretty complicated (also, very dependent on the whole project, so not easily reusable in mine).

I would like to try and use an IE ActiveX control, load an HTML that embeds a Flash Control, then get the HWND of this control do some application specific things (already implemented in my project). Is this possible? How?

Comment: Flash itself is an OCX control. what do you need ?

Comment: Which part needs clarification? I thought I explained it well. If I embed the Flash OCX control, it performs poorly. If I load the same swf in a browser, it performs very well. I want to load the Flash inside an embedded browser, but keep the full control which I have with directly embedding.

Comment: Well, if you place OCX over a form, it has perform well as with browsers. Are you sure your form does't have any operations which performs on UI main thread ?

Comment: Why are you so sure about that? I researched the problem, and it is explained on the page I linked. It is possible to query "dirty" rectangles from the Flash player and request it to redraw one particular rectangle, however it is not straightforward.

Comment: in browser Flash player are windowless (otherwise background html cannot show through a transparent mode swf.) Make your ActiveX container support windowless activation first.